# SSKeyChain - что за зверь?

Tags: ios, xcode

Доброе утро!

Пишу своё первое приложение под iOS. В нем задумана защита от некоторых повторяющихся действий с одного и того же девайса пользователя (нескольких, если apple аккаунт общий). Авторизация "логин-пароль" на уровне приложения как таковая отсутствует, поэтому необходимо было реализовать идентификацию скрытую.
Удобно бы было генерить случайное число, которое бы хранилось где-нибудь у пользователя и оставалось неизменным даже при переустановки приложения.

Начал читать. Узнал про SSKeyChain. Но вот только опыта не хватает понять логику его работы... Объясните пожалуйста доступным языком!

**Мои предположения:**
(пожалуйста, поправьте если я не прав!)

1) У **каждого** пользователя есть **единый** аккаунт Apple, к которому привязываются **все приложения** на **одном** девайсе, а соответственно и хранилище на устройстве. Либо это облако для **одного аккаунта и нескольких устройств** для данного аккаунта (которое и называется keychain)?

2) Доступ к нему имеет библиотека SSKeyChain (через фреймворк секьюрити), при помощи которой я для **конкретного своего приложения** могу записывать **любые данные** со своими ключами (пароль к приложению, логин, цветовую схему)... чтобы при переустановке приложения, оно смогло проверить "есть ли уже настройки в KeyChain для меня?" и взять данные оттуда. Вроде аналога NSUserDefaults/SharedPreferences (ios/android), только не удаляющегося после переустановки приложения.

3) Возможность потерять данные из KeyChain у пользователя девайса есть только **при смене** Apple аккаунта либо действий со стороны Apple.

Так? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keychain - это криптографически защищённое хранилище, оптимизированное под хранение небольших данных (не стоит туда складывать поэмы, оно предназначено для паролей, различных секретов итд). Хранилище в iOS одно, единое для всех приложений. Доступ даётся только в пределах песочницы (то есть нельзя читать данные других программ), причём доступ идёт опираясь на provision profile. Хранилище может быть сброшено только при одном условии - выполнен сброс на заводские настройки, поэтому можно быть уверенным в сохранности данных и доступа к ним после переустановки приложения. Посему по вашим пунктам:

1. Хранилище не привязано к аккаунтам или Apple ID. Однако, отдельные ключи **могут** сохраняться и синхронизироваться через iCloud, для этого на ключ должен выставиться отдельный атрибут.
2. В отличие от OSX, в iOS можно писать строго в свой раздел, не имея возможности чтения/записи ключей, созданных другими программами. Данные сохраняются между переустановками приложения, на это вполне можно заложиться. Однако, сброс устройства сбросит также и keychain.
3. Смена apple id не влияет, случаев удалённого ресета со стороны Apple вроде зафиксировано не было.

Comment: Супер! Спасибо огромное! В моём случае необходимо идентифицировать действия пользователя в рамках одного устройства - запретить повторные действия с одного девайса. Приложение без авторизации и поэтому в качестве идентификатора принял решение генерить случайный ключ-комбинацию (32 знака) при первом входе, записывать в keychain и производить проверку по этому полю в будущем (при условии что приложение могут переустановить). Скажите, это решение мне подойдет в данном случае? )

Comment: да, вполне подходит